# Unknown columns error in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am calculating radius between loading and delivery points.

I have made a query for it but its giving me error :

unknown column distance1

Here is the query:

```
SELECT ( ( Acos(Sin('49.4634' * Pi() / 180) * Sin(
                `locationlatitudestart` * Pi() / 180)
                       +
                           Cos(
                           '49.4634' * Pi() / 180) * Cos(
                           `locationlatitudestart` * Pi()
                           /
                           180) * Cos((
                                '3.54404' - `locationlongitudestart` ) * Pi() /
                                      180)) *
                    180 / Pi() ) * 60 * 1.1515 ) AS distance1,
       ( ( Acos(Sin('48.8637' * Pi() / 180) * Sin(
                `locationlatitudeend` * Pi() / 180) +
                  Cos
                    (
                    '48.8637' * Pi() / 180) * Cos(
                  `locationlatitudeend` * Pi() / 180) *
                  Cos
                    ((
                         '2.36109' - `locationlongitudeend` ) * Pi() / 180)) *
           180 / Pi
           ()
         ) * 60 * 1.1515 )                       AS distance2,
       ( ( Acos(Sin('49.4634' * Pi() / 180) * Sin(
                `locationlatitudeend` * Pi() / 180) +
                  Cos
                    (
                    '49.4634' * Pi() / 180) * Cos(
                  `locationlatitudeend` * Pi() / 180) *
                  Cos
                    ((
                         '3.54404' - `locationlongitudeend` ) * Pi() / 180)) *
           180 / Pi
           ()
         ) * 60 * 1.1515 )                       AS distance3,
       ( ( Acos(Sin('48.8637' * Pi() / 180) * Sin(
                `locationlatitudestart` * Pi() / 180)
                +
                    Cos(
                    '48.8637' * Pi() / 180) * Cos(`locationlatitudestart` * Pi()
                                                  / 180)
                    *
                    Cos((
                         '2.36109' - `locationlongitudestart` ) * Pi() / 180)) *
           180 /
           Pi
             () ) * 60 * 1.1515 )                AS distance4
FROM   instant_quotes
WHERE  distance1 <= locationradiusstart
       AND distance2 <= locationradiusend
        OR distance3 <= locationradiusend
           AND distance3 <= locationradiusstart
```

Comment: Thanks for indenting my code

Comment: You cannot use the column alias with WHERE in this way. You can use HAVING, or a subquery, or quote that whole first bit again, or (better idea) construct a function that calculates the distance.

Comment: Why aren't you doing the calculations before the query? or use stored procedures?

Comment: @Strawberry Can you give me an example how can I use it with a function ?

Comment: Google is your friend

Comment: Well I do know how to use functions but i want an idea with my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below query - make use of having clause rather than where --

```
 SELECT ((ACOS( SIN( '49.4634' * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( `LocationLatitudeStart` * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( '49.4634' * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( `LocationLatitudeStart` * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ( '3.54404' - `LocationLongitudeStart` ) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( ) ) *60 * 1.1515 ) AS distance1 ,
     ((ACOS( SIN( '48.8637' * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( `LocationLatitudeEnd` * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( '48.8637' * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( `LocationLatitudeEnd` * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ( '2.36109' - `LocationLongitudeEnd` ) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( ) ) *60 * 1.1515 ) AS distance2,
     ((ACOS( SIN( '49.4634' * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( `LocationLatitudeEnd` * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( '49.4634' * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( `LocationLatitudeEnd` * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ( '3.54404' - `LocationLongitudeEnd` ) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( ) ) *60 * 1.1515 ) AS distance3 , 
    ((ACOS( SIN( '48.8637' * PI( ) /180 ) * SIN( `LocationLatitudeStart` * PI( ) /180 ) + COS( '48.8637' * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( `LocationLatitudeStart` * PI( ) /180 ) * COS( ( '2.36109' - `LocationLongitudeStart` ) * PI( ) /180 ) ) *180 / PI( ) ) *60 * 1.1515 ) AS distance4 
    FROM instant_quotes having distance1 <= LocationRadiusStart AND distance2 <= LocationRadiusEnd OR distance3 <= LocationRadiusEnd AND distance3 <= LocationRadiusStart
```

Comment: Well now it says Unknown column LocationRadiusStart' in 'having clause'

Comment: Oh its fixed. Thanks buddy. No one else was trying to be friendly